# Jenkins: How to run test on multiple slaves in parallel?

Tags: jenkins

How to run test on multiple slaves in parallel? Below is the requirement.

1. I have a Jenkins job A.
2. 5 slaves are connected to A.
3. Test X need to be run on all 5 slaves. Also need to see the status of the test on an independent console.
4. Result form the slave need to be independently published
5. Currently test X is run on only one slave and rest 4 slave's tests are in Queue.

I used **"Execute concurrent builds if necessary"** but, it just divides same test on 5 slaves so it does not do what I intend. What is the workaround here?

Comment: When you write host you mean Jenkins slave ?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins slaves